# Memory error despite having ample RAM

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with 8GB RAM. `memory.limit()` shows `8135`. I ran into memory issue even though what I'm trying to do does not seem humongous at all (compared to other memory-related questions on SO).

Basically I'm matching firm's ID with their industry. `ref.table` is the data frame where I store ID and industry for reference.

```
matchid <- function(id) {
  firm.industry <- ref.table$industry[ref.table$id==id]
  firm.industry <- as.character(firm.industry[1]) # Sometimes same ID has multiple industries. I just pick one.
  resid <<- c(resid, firm.industry)
}
resid <- c()
invisible( lapply(unmatched.id, matchid) ) # unmatched.id is the vector of firms' ID to be matched
```

The `unmatched.id` vector is about 60,000-element long. Still I got the error "Cannot allocate vector of **41.8kb** size" (Only 41.8kb!) Windows task manager shows full RAM usage at all time.

Is it because my function is too unwieldy somehow? I can't imagine it's the vector size causing problems.

(PS: I do gc() and rm() frequently)

Comment: Just because you do `gc` and `rm` does not ensure that you will get your memory "compacted". You need contiguous memory blocks and it's perfectly possible that your prior activities have fragmented your memory. Furthermore, you have system and other applications competeing for memory. Shutdown. Restart with no other applications. Do only the coding needed to create this object and you will have not difficulties. (And this is surely a duplicate question, so next time do a search before posting.)

Comment: And do note that the value is *an extra* 41.8kb block. Whatever you are doing is exhausting all the RAM and R cannot get another chunk of the required size to complete the operation.

Comment: Unwieldy? Yes. When you grow objects as in `resid <<- c(resid, firm.industry)`, R has to copy the entire vector every time you append a new element. And the use of `<<-` is generally frowned upon. I'm just guessing but you could probably do all this just with `unique(ref.table$industry[ref.table$id %in% unmatched.id])`.

Comment: @DWin I know that this continuous block issue has been asked before, but I'm not sure what part of my code is causing it. I will follow joran advice and fix that part of my code.

Comment: look closely, you have exponential growth in `resid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking up a vector of unmatched id's in `ref.table$id`, and finding the corresponding index

```
## first match, one for each unmatched.id, NA if no match
idx <- match(unmatched.id, ref.table$id)
## matching industries
resid <- ref.table$industry[idx]
```

This is 'vectorized' so much more efficient than an lapply.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following to see if it quits giving you memory complaints

```
 lapply(unmatched.id, function(id) as.character(ref.table$industry[ref.table$id==id]))
```

If the above works, then wrap it in  `unlist( ..,  use.names=FALSE)`

#### or try using data.table

```
library(data.table)
ref.table <- data.table(ref.table, key="id") 
ref.table[.(unmatched.id), as.character(industry)]
```

Comment: Your `lapply` code works fine. I think the memory issue is caused by my `resid <- c(resid, firm.industry)` instead. The reason I have to do that is to create a "result" vector (`resid`) that list the corresponding industry for each ID in `new.id`. (In other words, `resid` and `new.id` list industry and ID of the same firms).

In other language, I could use a for-loop, iterating through each element of `new.id` and change the corresponding element in `resid`. But, using `lapply` in R, the function in `lapply` returns after each element. That's why I had to modify a global var to create `resid`

Comment: I'm not sure things work the way you understand them to work ;)     In any case, try the second method

Comment: Could you please explain what I'm misunderstanding? For right now, I managed to have a solution (below), but for the purpose of learning, I'd really appreciate your comments. Whenever you have time!

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully get what your take on it is, but :   `" (In other words, resid and new.id list industry and ID of the same firms)"`  How is this _not_ being accomplished with `lapply` ?